# How to display something similar like the splash screen during a 10-30 sec load document process in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF application has an import file function. Sometimes the process takes 1-2 sec but sometimes it is 20-30 sec. For this cases I would like to display something similar as the built in splash screen, and disable any UI interaction.

Although I know I can display a borderless modal window with a custom background image, before I reinvent the wheel I am asking if there is a better idea, or pre-written (open source) component for it.

I also have doubt how can I implement this delayed thing. I mean I do not want to show and disappear this window for 1-2 secs, just for cases that take longer. Well this is a separate topic I know but both questions belong to the question to be solved in the title.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`BusyIndicator` control of the Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator). It disables the background so user can't use the application while it's displayed. You also have a `DisplayAfter` property to delay the visibility of the control.